# Angular filter with multiple checkboxes in separate filters

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, filter

I do something wrong because I can't achieve the result that I need.

My JSON data looks like this

```
[{
type_id: 1, 
brand_id: 0,
name: 'Title',
description: 'Description',
img: 'url'
},...]
```

So I need to filter data by `type_id` and `brand_id`
It has not to be a complicated task but stuck a lot and I will appreciate for any help from you I just can't handle it for now.

And this is how my view looks like. I have two filters that generated by ng-repeat
and ng-repeat for devices I need to filter by type and brand filter.

```
// filter 1
<div class="filters">
   <h3 class="filters__title">Choose by type</h3>
   <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-arrow-prev"></div>
      <div class="swiper-arrow-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-overflow">
         <div class="swiper-wrapper filter" data-id="type">
            <div class="swiper-slide filter__checkbox" ng-repeat="item in types">
               <input type="checkbox" name="{{item.id}}" id="filter-{{item.id}}" ng-model="item.id" ng-checked="item.id">
               <label for="filter-{{item.id}}">
               <span>{{item.type}}</span>
               </label>
            </div>
            <!-- /item -->
         </div>
         <!-- /filter -->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- /filters -->

// filter 2
<div class="filters">
   <h3 class="filters__title">Choose by brand</h3>
   <div class="swiper-container">
      <div class="swiper-arrow-prev"></div>
      <div class="swiper-arrow-next"></div>
      <div class="swiper-overflow">
         <div class="swiper-wrapper filter" data-id="brands">
            <div class="swiper-slide filter__checkbox" ng-repeat="brand in brands">
               <input type="checkbox" name="{{brand.id}}" id="brand-{{brand.id}}" ng-model="brand.id">
               <label for="brand-{{brand.id}}">
               <img ng-src="{{brand.img}}" alt="">
               <span>{{brand.name}}</span>
               </label>
            </div>
            <!-- /item -->
         </div>
         <!-- /filter -->
      </div>
      <!-- /swiper-overflow -->
   </div>
   <!-- /swiper-container -->
</div>
<!-- /filters -->


<div class="card" ng-repeat="device in devices">
   <div class="card__wrap">
      <figure>
         <img ng-src="{{device.img}}" alt="">
      </figure>
      <!-- /img -->
      <h3 class="card__title">{{device.model}}</h3>
   </div>
</div>
<!-- /card -->


angular.module('app', []).controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataJSON', '_', function($scope, dataJSON, _) {
            $scope.filterContainer = [];

            // get Data
            dataJSON.getPromise().then(function(data) {
                $scope.brands = data.brands;
                $scope.devices = data.devices;
                $scope.types = data.device_types;

                return data.devices;
            }).then(function(data) {

            })
        }])
```

Comment: Not knowing the answer to this question is compelling me to study Angular Js

Comment: Not getting what you are exactly looking for..

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for filter

```
// let take two input 
<input ng-model="type_id_model"><input ng-model="brand_id_model">


// filter 1
    ng-repeat="item in types | filter:{type_id : type_id_model}"
// filter 2
    ng-repeat="brand in brands | filter:{brand_id : brand_id_model}"
```

Comment: No sure if it what I want 
I need to filter devices and not filter types and brands. 
And also need to note that it's checkboxes there, so it could be more than one type and brand there 
But abyway thanks for post

Comment: Json for devide object have type_id,brand_id?

Comment: Yes, it has type_id and brand_id

Comment: its in array right?and you need to select any one at a time?

Comment: Array with Objects and I need to show only these ones that choosed by filters

Comment: Can you write all json objects here?